# IOS: How to send an Image View back and front

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In my storyboard I have a view on which I have an `ImageView` and a `Button`. The `ImageView` is currently covering my button and I would like to put the button over the ImageView. I found similar topics which were solved by going to "Editor" -> "Arrange" -> "Send to Front", however that was done for `UIViews` and this option is passive for `ImageView` and `Buttons`.

So how can I send my `ImageView` to background? Is the best solution for this to add an additional view only for the `Button` and then bring it to front?

Comment: In the left menu drag&drop up/down the elements. The elements at the bottom are the one "on top".

Comment: In storyboard, at the left bottom of the screen, you see a "Show Document Outline" button. It opens a list of controllers that are on the storyboard. As @Larme already explained, you can rearrange the ui elements.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can rearrange your views on storyboard:

[image]

First view in order will be hidden by next view.

Maybe this options will be also useful for your running application:

```
myImageView.layer.zPosition = -5;
myImageView.layer.zPosition = 5;
```

Like in HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 3):

The solution was to move the view components up and down in the "Document Outline" section.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could've solved the problem using the `bringSubviewToFront` function:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.yourButtonControl];
```